# Custom EditTextDialog is broken in Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm currently working on an application and I have and unwanted behavior on my custom EditText Dialog. Here's the XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_dialog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/close_dialog"
        android:id="@+id/cancel_dialog"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/valid_dialog" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/validate_dialog"
        android:id="@+id/valid_dialog"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>S7

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the class for the TextEditDialog

```
package com.fitme.staffbooker;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;


public class EditTextDialog extends Dialog {

private EditText editText;
public boolean dismissed = false;

public EditTextDialog(Context context, String title) {
    super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
    setTitle(title);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_dialog);

    findViewById(R.id.valid_dialog).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismissed = true;
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.cancel_dialog).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancel();
        }
    });
}

public void setHint(String str) {
    editText.setHint(str);
}

public void setText(String str) {
    editText.setText(str);
}

public void setInputType(int type) {
    editText.setInputType(type);
}

public String getValue() {
    return editText.getText().toString();
}
}
```

Here's the output i'm having on my Galaxy S7 Edge : [image: S7Preview]

But when I'm running my app on a Galaxy SIII Emulator it seems broken :

[image: 4.3 Error]

It seems that this only happens on 4.3 and below. I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: I think it would help if you post the custom EdiTextDialog class (I think the problem resides in the Theme you are building your dialog with ) ...

Comment: As I can see some rests of textViews :) in that problematic Dialog, like some points, I only imagine that it doesn't scale correctly the view. Why don't you try to set lower text sizes and see if then it fits correctly.

Comment: And also I'd suggest to try to set the LinearLayout height to wrapContent...

Comment: @Rucsi I was about to edit the question with the changes you suggested, but I tried one more thing and I found it, the problem was the layout-margin in each TextView, changed it to padding a it works ! Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it!!